# Meaning of Calligraphy Phrase "sumi tsugi"

Tags: calligraphy

I came across the phrase "sumi tsugi" somewhere (cannot remember where and therefore cannot cite the source). The phrase was in English so I do not know which kanji for "tsugi" would be appropriate, 次 or 継ぎ. Thus my question: Does this phrase refer to dipping the brush into ink a second time while writing one kanji, or does it refer to going back into a completed kanji to correct/finesse a stroke (which I do know is strictly forbidden)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [list of calligraphy terms](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9B%B8%E9%81%93%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7#%E3%81%95%E8%A1%8C) in which sumi tsugi is

> 墨継ぎ（すみつぎ）とは、文の途中で筆に墨を付けること。

Which means dipping the brush into ink a second time while writing one **sentence**. The 日本国語大辞典 confirms that it is only used about sentences (incl. haiku, waka, etc.).